# Extracting the linear equation for a circular-circular regression

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, nonlinear-regression, circular-statistics

I am trying to create a predictive model using a relationship found by the `lm.circular` function from the `circular` package. The function, however, only provides statistics of the models fit and the intercept/coefficients, and I have been struggling to put together the equation of the linear model using these outputs. How can I take the outputs from this function and develop an equation to predict the y variable?

I've done some reading in[Jammalamadaka, S. Rao and SenGupta, A. (2001)](https://books.google.com/books?id=sKqWMGqQXQkC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=Sarma%20and%20Jammalamadaka%20(1993)&source=bl&ots=f5I7QqVtiL&sig=ACfU3U2r3aWpdCIUEzPJ_TRotngdpuOqKA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjMzKPbpNfgAhXmyoMKHY5uBbQQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Sarma%20and%20Jammalamadaka%20(1993)&f=false), [Downs and Mardia (2002)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4140611.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A00227057da02caed02c10ad3e572aa94) and have included an example below taken from [Pewsey, Neuhauser and Graeme (2013)](http://circstatinr.st-andrews.ac.uk/), but am still unsure of how to construct those relationships from what R is giving me.

```
library(circular)

psideg <- c(356,97,211,232,343,292,157,302,335,302,324,85,324,340,157,238,254,146,232,122,329)

thetadeg <- c(119,162,221,259,270,29,97,292,40,313,94,45,47,108,221,270,119,248,270,45,23)

cpsirad <- circular(psideg*2*pi/360); cthetarad <- circular(thetadeg*2*pi/360)

circ.lm <- lm.circular(type = "c-c", y = cthetarad, x = cpsirad, order = 1)

plot.default(cthetarad, cpsirad, xlab = "cthetarad", ylab = "cpsirad", xlim = c(0, 7), ylim = c(-2, 7))

circ.lm$rho
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 0.502289

circ.lm$coefficients
#>                    [,1]      [,2]
#> (Intercept)  0.01441183 0.1145101
#> cos.x        0.33465348 0.5494121
#> sin.x       -0.07478683 0.4821004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using edits and additions from Ulric Lund, one of the `circular` package co-authors, the following script utilizes the model coefficients to recreate the model manually for the purposes of building a predictive relationship.

```
## Checking how to get fitted values
### Get model coefficients
( cf <- circ.lm$coefficients )
#>                    [,1]      [,2]
#> (Intercept)  0.01441183 0.1145101
#> cos.x        0.33465348 0.5494121
#> sin.x       -0.07478683 0.4821004

### Model calculations provided by package co-author Ulric Lund
costheta <- cf[1,1]+cf[2,1]*cos(psirad)+cf[3,1]*sin(psirad)
sintheta <- cf[1,2]+cf[2,2]*cos(psirad)+cf[3,2]*sin(psirad)
# Quadrant-correct version of atan:
calcfits <- atan2(sintheta, costheta)
```

The `calcfits` is the calculated values of the manual model and the `diffits` shows the fit between models. The difference of 6.28319 demonstrates the circular nature of the data and can be accounted for by adding 2pi because of the 1:1 relationship as visualized in the plot outputs.

```
### Difference between model and hand-calculated fitted values
( difffits <- round(circ.lm$fitted-calcfits,5) )
#> Circular Data: 
#> Type = angles 
#> Units = radians 
#> Template = none 
#> Modulo = asis 
#> Zero = 0 
#> Rotation = counter 
#>       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9 
#> 0.00000 0.00000 6.28319 6.28319 0.00000 6.28319 6.28319 6.28319 0.00000 
#>      10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18 
#> 6.28319 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 6.28319 6.28319 6.28319 6.28319 
#>      19      20      21 
#> 6.28319 0.00000 0.00000

## Making a fitted line plot from the model results
plot.default(cpsirad, cthetarad, xlab = "cpsirad", ylab = "cthetarad", xlim = c(0, 6.5), ylim = c(0, 6.5))
lines.default(cpsirad[order(cpsirad)], circ.lm$fitted[order(cpsirad)])
```

[image]

```
## ... same data but adjusted for 2*pi
thetaPlot  <- ifelse(cpsirad < 5.5, cthetarad, cthetarad + 2*pi)
fittedPlot <- ifelse(cpsirad < 5.5, circ.lm$fitted, circ.lm$fitted + 2*pi)
plot.default(cpsirad, thetaPlot, xlab = "cpsirad", ylab = "cthetarad")
lines.default(cpsirad[order(cpsirad)], fittedPlot[order(cpsirad)])
```

[image]

Other notes include a error in the original plot code that had theta and psi switched, and further information on using p values. The output p values from the package test whether a higher order trigonometric polynomial is warranted. The null hypotheses in this case is that the current model (with only first order terms) is sufficient. The p-values are not small, so we don't reject these null hypotheses, and so we treat the estimated model as the final model.

```
circ.lm$p.values
#>            [,1]      [,2]
#> [1,] 0.09971087 0.9474847

#Rho output can be used similarly to r^2
circ.lm$rho
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 0.502289
```